# &...; in RDF/XML — is this a standard RDF prefix expression?

Tags: xml, rdf, wordnet, rdfs

I downloaded WordNet2.0 fullset.  In the RDF/XML document, wnfull.rdfs, there are elements like this the following that use, e.g., `&wn20schema;AdverbSynset` as attribute values (in places where URIs would be expected). I know how `#`, `url/` and `value:` are commonly used, but what is this `&...;` notation?

```xml
<rdfs:Class rdf:about="&wn20schema;Synset" />  
<rdfs:Class rdf:about="&wn20schema;AdjectiveSynset" />  
<rdfs:Class rdf:about="&wn20schema;AdjectiveSatelliteSynset" />  
<rdfs:Class rdf:about="&wn20schema;AdverbSynset" />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`&wn20schema;` is an entity reference.

The XML document should contain or point to its expansion, i.e., something like

```
<!ENTITY wn20schema "…">
```

`&wn20schema;` will be replaced with `…`.

References:

- XML 1.0: http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#sec-physical-struct

  - See also [examples](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#sec-entexpand).
- XML 1.1: http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml11-20060816/#sec-physical-struct

  - See also [examples](http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml11-20060816/#sec-entexpand).